# Remote debugging Azure functions - .netcoreapp3.1 framework with visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, remote-debugging, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to remote debug azure function but every time getting below exception, I have publish function project with debug mode, and tried from cloud explorer to attach debugger but getting below exception

[image]

[image]

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'functionappurl'.  The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated.at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)
> at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase`1.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)

Also on portal [image] done this settings
and while publishing below is settings of publish profile [image]

Comment: Is your problem solved or still facing it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I will check it tomorrow and reply it

Comment: If your problem was solved, could you please post an answer below ?

Comment: My problem is solved in one way  i.e. by following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCbusedCNqY , but I won't able to solve my problem using cloud explorer